# Arara crashes after update

Tags: arara

After updating `arara`, I have a problem when I run it:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

`C:\Users\Name\Documents\arara test.tex`

Give me:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <<> at index 0: <arara> @{userhome}\arara\rules
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.mvel.configuration.LocalConfiguration$toExecutionOptions$preprocessedPaths$3.invoke(LocalConfiguration.kt:78)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.mvel.configuration.LocalConfiguration$toExecutionOptions$preprocessedPaths$3.invoke(LocalConfiguration.kt:78)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:210)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:210)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:210)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:786)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toSet(_Sequences.kt:827)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.mvel.configuration.LocalConfiguration.toExecutionOptions(LocalConfiguration.kt:86)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.load(ConfigurationUtils.kt:73)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLI.run(CLI.kt:215)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:204)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:17)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse(CliktCommand.kt:396)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse$default(CliktCommand.kt:393)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:411)
        at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:436)
        at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLIKt.main(CLI.kt:290)
```

It is `arara` version 6.1.1, `java` version 1.8.0_291 and `miktex` version 21.6.28

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: works ok for me, but my java version is a bit older.

Comment: See [the CHANGELOG for version 6](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed). It's a documented and intended change to remove the arara shorthand syntax. Simply use the more elaborate syntax that has been there for a few versions and you are fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will uninstall reinstall `arara`, `miktex` and `java` to try.
@TeXnician, the [quickstart](https://ctan.gutenberg.eu.org/support/arara/doc/) guide from 6.0.1 release use the `arara` command.

Comment: @Arnaud Paulo sent me an special yaml for a test, with it I got the error to. So I think you have some special settings somewhere.

Comment: I am writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*(arara developer here)*</sup>

Looking closely at exception thrown,

```
Illegal char <<> at index 0: <arara> @{userhome}\arara\rules
```

I can determine the error is located in your configuration file (`araraconfig.yaml` or similar name). In series 5 (as seen in the corresponding [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-2020-03-03) entry and [issue #26](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/26)), the `<arara>`shorthand was marked as deprecated and announced to be removed in the next major version (series 6). That's why an update from 5 to 6 "crashed". `:)`

I would guess your configuration file currently looks like

```yaml
!config
paths:
- <arara> @{userhome}\arara\rules
```

There are two issues:

- The `<arara>` shorthand is no more, so we need to remove it.
- The `{@userhome}` was replaced my `@{user.home}` so we need to updated.

A new configuration file would be:

```yaml
!config
paths:
- '@{user.home}\arara\rules'
```

That would solve the issue.

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much @PauloCereda, It works now !
Thank you too Ulrike Fischer for your responsiveness !